# C++ namespace issue

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am having three classes all of them are from different namespaces as shown below:

classA.h

```
namespace outer
{
    namespace inner
    {
        class ClassA
        {
           ....
        };
    }
}
```

classB.h

```
namespace inner
{
    class ClassB
    {
        ...
    };
}
```

classC.h

```
#include <classB.h>

namespace outer
{
    namespace inner2
    {
        using inner::ClassB; // error here, says outer::inner2::ClassB has not been declared.

        class ClassC
        {
            ....
        };
     }
}
```

I am stuck at this please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need

```
using ::inner::ClassB;
```

because in `namespace outer`, you have 2 options for `inner`

- `::inner` - global namespace
- `::outer::inner` - `outer` namespace

By default, `using inner::ClassB;` will try to import `ClassB` from `outer::inner`.

Comment: ya i know that but why am getting this error it has nothing to do with it, both my classes are in seperate files so that should not make any difference to it, am i rite?

Comment: @shobi different files, same namespace. You're including somewhere a file that declares namespace `inner` as part of `outer`, so if you want to use the global namespace, you have to explicitly state `::inner`.

Comment: cant we have some other fix for it bcoz the two files are completely independent of each other so that doesnt make any difference if it does can u please explain it to me, why is it so?

Comment: @shobi they're not independent. It's not visible maybe, but they aren't. What other fix do you want? What's wrong with this? Another fix is renaming your namespaces. I'd personally remove `inner` from global scope.

Comment: when did i say that ur solution is not correct i know it is, but still how these two files are dependent?

Comment: @shobi my guess is `classC.h` indirectly (or directly) includes `classA.h`.

Comment: guess it is. are u confident about that?

Comment: @shobi :)) care to make a wager?

Comment: do u have any documentation of it or something which can make it a bit clear

Comment: @shobi to test this, do this simple change - from **classC.h** remove **all** includes except `classB.h`. From **classB.h** remove **all** includes.

Comment: @shobi any C++ book you have at hand. Or you can google *nested namespace*.

Comment: i know about nested namespaces and even i knew the solution which u gave, but my question how come these two files are dependent?

Comment: @shobi you do realize I can't answer that given the code, right?

Comment: @shobi post in www.ideone.com

Comment: @shobi ok then. Your compiler is broken.

Comment: this is not the solution am looking for

Comment: @shobi, that can't be the full code, you've only shown header files, not a .cc file. The answer is correct, so I don't know what kind of answer you're looking for